# any equivalent of -fshort-enums in __attribute__ or #pragma?

Tags: gcc, enums

I'd like to specify some but not all enum types as short-enums. Therefore, the compiler option -fshort-enums seems not the best choice.

Comment: Like [__attribute__((packed))](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.2/gcc/Type-Attributes.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `__attribute__((packed))`.

Like:

```
typedef enum{
    X,
    Y,
    Z
} __attribute__((packed)) shortEnumExample;
```

For less than 256 values the enum should be compiled as 8-bit, for more values (or if you assign bigger values) it will become bigger.

I am not sure if this is compiler specific, but it should work at least for GCC and Clang. (I guess the `-fshort-enums` parameter is from one of those.)